# Display HTML in an OutOfBrowser Silverlight App

Tags: silverlight

Imagine I have a Silverlight HTML control that displays web pages inside the SL plugin (this control internally uses IFrame).
So far, when the SL application is running in the browser, the HTML control works as expected.
Is there any chance (and sense) for this scenario to work in a OutOfBrowser SL application? I'm asking just out of curiosity, not ranting.
Thanks!

Best Regards,
Kiril

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

Source: http://silverlight.net/forums/t/111713.aspx

Comment: Care to elaborate, because I was thinking of using an http:// address and display the content of the web page in a SL OOB application

Answer (score 0):

The HTML control is going to be a Wrapper for the MSHTML component, hence it ought to work fine out of browser.  However the best way to find out is to knock up a little test and try it.